# jquery focus() for Tab jumps twice in Asp.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tabs, focus

I have the code below for managing tab in Asp.net page and when I press the tab in TextBox1 it jumps to an element after TextBox2 instead of TextBox2, what am I doing wrong?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#TextBox1").live('keypress', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 9) {
               $("#TextBox2").focus();
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the correct form, I needed to prevent it fro doing its default and also it doesn't work with keydown, since it was a tab so I used a keydown.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#TextBox1").keydown(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var kCode = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
            if (kCode == 9) {
                $("#TextBox2").focus();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I was just about to say - you need to `.preventDefault()` or `return false;`.

Comment: I just spent about an hour checking and re-checking my JS thinking I was doing something wrong in my code. Nope, correct element being focused on - however setting the preventDefault() did the trick! I had no idea this was a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Running example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xsqrd

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#TextBox1").live('keypress', function (e) {
        var kCode = e.keyCode || e.charCode; //cross browser check
        //Mozilla and Safari define e.charCode, while IE defines e.keyCode which returns the ASCII value
        if (kCode == 9) {
           $("#TextBox2").focus();
        }
    });
});
```

[JavaScript Madness: Keyboard Events](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html)

Comment: explain what var kCode = e.keyCode || e.charCode; does and you'll have my upvote.

Comment: It is checking to see how the browser handles the keypress event.  Mozilla vs IE...etc

Comment: Nice work, i didn't know that it did it differently. I'm pretty sure i had similar issues on a side project once and ended up doing a more time consuming work around.

Comment: thanks . I was testing in Firefox and now I also test it in IE and chrome , I get the same result in Firefox with your code and it doesn't work in IE and Chrome. maybe it's some problem in ASP.Net